# Functionality of a recursion function in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I found a recursion function in GeeksforGeeks website. Can someone explain how this function works?

```
int fun1(int x, int y)
{ 
   if(x == 0) 
       return y; 
   else
      return fun1(x - 1, x + y); 
}
```

It says it will return y+(x+x-1+x-2+x-3+...2+1). I appreciate if someone can explain why. I thought it should return y+1 as when x becomes 1 on stack memory, it will return y+1 (since x-1 becomes 0), and eventually it will return the other functions on stack as y+1 until the early first function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that when `x == 1`, this returns `y+1`. But for the other cases, remember that `y` is also different between the calls. For example, when `x==2`, it calls `fun1(2 - 1, 2 + y)`, so for the next invocation `y` is two more than it was before. This next invocation has `x == 1`, so it ends up returning one more than the `y` it has, which itself is `2` more than the original value, so the call to `fun1(2, y)` returns `y + 2 + 1`.

An illustration of the call stack might be more helpful. Let's say we call `fun1(5, 7)`.

- `fun1(5, 7)` returns the value of `fun1(5 - 1, 5 + 7)`
- `fun1(4, 12)` returns the value of `fun1(4 - 1, 4 + 12)`
- `fun1(3, 16)` returns the value of `fun1(3 - 1, 3 + 16)`
- `fun1(2, 19)` returns the value of `fun1(2 - 1, 2 + 19)`
- `fun1(1, 21)` returns the value of `fun1(1 - 1, 1 + 21)`
- `fun1(0, 22)` returns 22.

Thus, all together (and rearranging slightly), the `fun1(5, 7)` call returned `7 + (5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1)`, as the documentation said.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. It now makes fully sense. Basically when x=1, it returns y'+1 ( I call y' as it's not the same as original y), where y'=x+y+x-1+x-2+...+3+2 :)

Comment: @EhsiCool Exactly. (And I considered going with the `y'` notation myself; I wish that were a legal variable name in C++ but it would confuse the parser)

Answer (score -1):

The function `fun()` calculates and returns `((1 + 2 … + x-1 + x) +y)` which is `x(x+1)/2 + y`. For example if `x` is `5` and `y` is `2`, then `fun()` should return `15 + 2 = 17`.